# Return all records for subquery result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have three tables products, portfolio_mapping, and category. Every product has multiple portfolio mappings and multiple categories. In the following query, I want to get all categories to which the product belongs. The following query only returns the category for which the condition is true. I would like to have all categories for the product when the condition is true.

I have used a subquery in `WHERE` clause, this returns a product_id.

Now for this product_id, I would like to get all categories. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

```
SELECT  c.category_names
FROM 
    product AS pd
LEFT JOIN
    portfolio_mapping AS p
    ON 
    pd.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    category_mapping AS c
    ON 
    pd.product_id = c.product_id  

WHERE pd.product_id IN
    ( SELECT c.product_id FROM category_mapping AS c 
        WHERE (p.portfolio_mapping_id = 1 AND p.value = 'Yes')  
            AND (c.category_id = 1 AND c.value = 'Yes')  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your subquery refers back to rows in the main query, you are only generating the IN list for some rows. You should recode your where clause to add all the same joins.

```
SELECT  c.category_names
FROM 
    product AS pd
LEFT JOIN
    portfolio_mapping AS p
    ON 
    pd.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    category_mapping AS c
    ON 
    pd.product_id = c.product_id  
WHERE pd.product_id IN
( 
SELECT c1.product_id FROM product AS pd1
JOIN portfolio_mapping AS p1 ON pd1.product_id = p1.product_id
JOIN category_mapping AS c1 ON pd1.product_id = c1.product_id  
WHERE (p1.portfolio_mapping_id = 1 AND p1.value = 'Yes')  
AND (c1.category_id = 1 AND c1.value = 'Yes')  
)
```

Personally I'd recode it to use WHERE EXISTS ().